# Pushing a repo with submodules to github

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

im a student with a large directory of previous projects/labs that ive worked on through college. I want to upload the entire folder of all my projects with individuals git repos to github in one giant repository for the sake of documentation. But after attempting to push all these projects, they appear as unclickable grey folders within github. How can I easily/quickly make it so those project's source code are able to be browsed on github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grey icon is the github icon for a git **submodule**, and it is pointing to an unreachable remote location.

You might just initialize git inside the folder

The quick way to fix this:

1) make another copy of this github repo on you local

2) git submodule update --init